# Can anyone explain what git cherry-pick <sha> does?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

As my concern here is, I have old commit in my another local branch [contains abc.cpp, def.cpp].

Now after few months I want use those changes, but in my current branch abc.cpp is upgraded. So is it like if I cherry pick then it will integrate changes of old abc.cpp into new abc.cpp [recent working directory copy]?

Comment: Note: `git cherry-pick` will soon (git 1.8.5/1.9) be able to cherry-pick "from the previous branch": see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18954079/6309).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The git-cherry-pick(1) man page says:

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one
>   introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working
>   tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

In plain English, this means that `git cherry-pick` applies commits from one branch to another, but does not preserve the original history or ancestry from the other branch in the way that a proper merge would do.

Think of it as applying a series of selected patches, rather than a full merge of two branches of history. Obviously, if you tend to make very small, atomic commits then cherry-picking looks exactly like applying a well-written patch. However, since you don't have common ancestors the way you do with merge or rebase, you may have a lot more conflicts to resolve if your commits aren't small and isolated.

Whether or not cherry-picking is a good idea is highly dependent on how you structure your commits. If it doesn't work for you, you can always do things more manually with `git format-patch` and `git apply` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's what it does. `cherry-pick` is applying a commit (or a range of them) as a patch to your branch (well, [almost as a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156459/what-are-the-differences-between-git-cherry-pick-and-git-show-patch-p1)).

You might have conflicts (like when you merge branches) since independent modifications have happened on your branches.

Comment: uh? Like a merge? But it doesn't record the merge like a classic merge do, since it is more like applying a patch. See the warning in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112

Comment: I agree the comparison isn't right, I wanted to emphasize that cherry-pick can have to deal with two unrelated modifications, like in a merge

Comment: Plus, a cherry-pick can use a *range* of commits ;)

Comment: Almost: you can mention a cherry-pick isn't *exactly* a patch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156459/what-are-the-differences-between-git-cherry-pick-and-git-show-patch-p1

Answer (score 2):

Note that with [git1.8.5/1.9 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/128a96c98442524c7f2eeef4757b1e48445f24ce/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L92-L95), git cherry-pick can now easily cherry-pick "from the previous branch":

> Just like "`git checkout -`" knows to check out and "`git merge -`" knows to merge the branch you were previously on, "`git cherry-pick`" now understands "`git cherry-pick -`" to pick from the previous branch.

See [commit 182d7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/182d7dc46b23b4a20985c93ea3a6ba3e6f267ff6) from [Hiroshige Umino (yaotti)](https://github.com/yaotti):

#### `cherry-pick`: allow "`-`" as abbreviation of '`@{-1}`'

> "`-`" abbreviation is handy for "`cherry-pick`" like "`checkout`" and "`merge`".
>
> **It's also good for uniformity that a "`-`" stands as the name of the previous branch where a branch name is accepted and it could not mean any other things like stdin**.